# No monitor input using a HDMI to DVI adapter

Tags: hdmi

Did I just buy a crappy HDMI to DVI adapter? Is my monitor too old? It's from, like, 2009, but it has a dvi-d port. The HDMI works fine through all this... I can pull the plug, put it in my TV and RPi displays in safe mode.

RPi works, I can SSH to it, view and edit /boot/config.txt. Can run tvservice and extract edid information which I can post tomorrow if necessary. EDID info pulls model number and modes correctly from what I can tell.

I have changed HDMI_safe=1 and commented everything else out. Still no DVI display from monitor.

Anything else suspicious before I go buy a new adapter?

Comment: The adaptors are simple pin for pin connections so it is unlikely anything is wrong (apart from a damaged pin) Try `config_hdmi_boost=4` to see if this helps.

Comment: I also tried an apple TV and received no signal. In config I tried config_HDMI_boost all the way up to 11. One at a time, with force_hotplug activated. I guess I need to find a source with DVI to test that connection in the monitor. The adapter was a cheap Chinese one. Probably will end up being the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a similar issue. In my case, I changed the DVI adaptor and everything worked fine. Apparently, the DVI adaptor was working fine with other electronics but when I used it with the PI I got the same warning as yours. So,

> try changing the DVI adaptor.

Hope, it helped someone.

Comment: And hey one more thing, if that doesn't work, consider re-installing the OS using ETCHER only. Don't go with Win32DiskManager as I've faced display issues when using it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I noticed that the metal housing of the DVI adapter did not come into contact with the ground of the HDMI, (apparently this problem occurs because raspberry pi does not have a grounding pin), I decided to force a contact between the two ends of the adapter housing.[image]

Comment: "force a contact" How?

Comment: You can put a clip or weld one end of the earth to the other, I can send you a more realistic image or video later, because I do not have the adapter at the moment.
But the important thing is to make the two lands have the same potential.